# Como testar a função .then com Jest?

Tags: react, typescript, assincronismo, jest, react-testing-library

Tenho a função abaixo no meu projeto **react**:

```
import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

export default async (node: HTMLElement | null, fileName: string) => {
  if (node) {
    return domtoimage.toBlob(node).then((blob) => {
      const file = new Blob([blob], { type: 'image/png' });
      saveAs(file, fileName);
    });
  }
  throw new Error('Node HTMLElement cannot be null');
};
```

Basicamente ele recebe um elmento HTML, transforma ele em imagem e faz o download usando o FileSaver.

**E eu fiz o teste abaixo pra essa função:**

```
import fileSaver from 'file-saver';
import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';
import htmlElementToImageDownload from '../domToImage';

describe('When execute domToImage function', () => {
  it('should return error if the element sent is null', async () => {
    htmlElementToImageDownload(null, 'test').then((data) => {
      expect(data).toThrowError(Error);
    });
  });

  it('should execute the function toBlob and saveAs', async () => {
    const spyGeteElementById = jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById');
    const spyToBlob = jest.spyOn(domtoimage, 'toBlob');
    const spySaveAs = jest.spyOn(fileSaver, 'saveAs');

    const mockElement = document.createElement('div');
    spyGeteElementById.mockReturnValue(mockElement);

    htmlElementToImageDownload(mockElement, 'test').then(() => {
      expect(spyToBlob).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(spySaveAs).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    spyToBlob.mockRestore();
    spySaveAs.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

But when I check the application's test coverage, it reports that the lines below (what's inside the "then") are not being tested.
Mas quando verifico a cobertura de testes, ele indica que as linhas abaixo ( que estão dentro do "then") não foram testadas:

```
const file = new Blob([blob], { type: 'image/png' });
saveAs(file, fileName);
```

**O que estou fazendo errado no teste?**

**Como posso testar o trecho da promise?**

Answer (score 0):

Faltou aguardar a resolução da *promise*.

Alias, não faz nem sentido declarar o teste como `async` se você não irá utilizar `await`.

Tem duas formas de se fazer isso, uma é utilizando o callback que você recebe do jest para declarar que a função terminou:

```
it('should execute the function toBlob and saveAs', (done) => {
  const spyGeteElementById = jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById');
  const spyToBlob = jest.spyOn(domtoimage, 'toBlob');
  const spySaveAs = jest.spyOn(fileSaver, 'saveAs');

  const mockElement = document.createElement('div');
  spyGeteElementById.mockReturnValue(mockElement);

  htmlElementToImageDownload(mockElement, 'test').then(() => {
    expect(spyToBlob).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spySaveAs).toHaveBeenCalled();

    spyToBlob.mockRestore();
    spySaveAs.mockRestore();

    done();
  });
});
```

E a outra é utilizar `await`, o que é possível se você estiver usando promises:

```
it('should execute the function toBlob and saveAs', async () => {
  const spyGeteElementById = jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById');
  const spyToBlob = jest.spyOn(domtoimage, 'toBlob');
  const spySaveAs = jest.spyOn(fileSaver, 'saveAs');

  const mockElement = document.createElement('div');
  spyGeteElementById.mockReturnValue(mockElement);

  await htmlElementToImageDownload(mockElement, 'test');

  expect(spyToBlob).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(spySaveAs).toHaveBeenCalled();

  spyToBlob.mockRestore();
  spySaveAs.mockRestore();
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas. Na primeira solução você só moveu os mockRestore pra dentro do arrow function da promise, a cobertura continua dizendo que aquele trecho não está sendo testado. 
E uma dúvida: pra que o done()? Diz que ele não existe aqui...

Comment: Você adicionou o `done` no argumento da função? A função declarada dentro do `then` é agendada para ser executada quando a _promise_ terminar de rodar, o seu código é de natureza assíncrona, e o jest não sabe quando que o teste terminou de rodar, a menos que você utilize um callback ou retorne uma promise, que é o que for feito nos respectivos exemplos 1 e 2.

Comment: Não tinha adicionado o `done` no argumento mesmo. Mas depois que adicionei começou a dar timeOut também: `thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.`

Comment: Então é provável que a função do `then` nunca foi invocada, algum erro ocorreu no seu código, e como você não tem um `catch` nessa promise, ele não foi capturado.

Comment: humm, testando manualmente tudo funcionou, mas vou colocar o catch pra ver o resultado.

Comment: Coloquei o catch, mas não cai nele também 

Comment: George, o `catch` que você colocou, foi o método da promise, ou foi um try/catch? É para você usar o primeiro: `htmlElementToImageDownload(mockElement, 'test').catch((err) => console.log('caiu no erro', err))`. De toda forma, acho que o seu problema já não é a respeito de como testar um código assíncrono com o Jest.

Comment: Coloquei o .catch mesmo, após o .then...